# mysqldbcompare and mysqldiff fails to compare

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When I compare two databases, mysqluc stucks in halfway and it shows error as follows:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ade\build\sb_0-14553893-1424966082.93\Python-2.7.6-windows-x86-32bit\
lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "scripts\mysqldiff.py", line 245, in <module>
  File ".\mysql\utilities\command\diff.py", line 149, in database_diff
  File ".\mysql\utilities\command\diff.py", line 92, in object_diff
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\dbcompare.py", line 646, in diff_objects
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\dbcompare.py", line 466, in _check_tables_struc
ture
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\database.py", line 1206, in get_object_definiti
on
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\server.py", line 1263, in exec_query
  File ".\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 339, in close
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.**
```

I have tried with both mysqldiff and mysqldbcompare command.

```
mysqldiff --server1=username:password@hostname:3307 --server2=username:pasword@localhost:3306 DB1:DB1 --force --difftype=sql --changes-for=server2

mysqldbcompare --server1=username:password@hostname:3307 --server2=username:pasword@localhost:3306 DB1:DB1 --run-all-test --difftype=sql changes-for=server2
```

It gets stuck on both commands.

I have tried to compared on both windows 7, windows 8.1 .

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If you ever resolved it let me know.

Comment: ME too. Just upgraded mysql sever from 5.7.4, in which it worked fine, to 5.7.9. What version of mysqld are you using? For mysql-utilities, I'm trying both 1.5.4 and 1.5.6. The 1.6.1 is in git, but that's complicated for me to install.

Comment: I solved my problem by restarting the mysqld service on the one server that was hanging. Try that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Database is Huge and some columns in tables are in "**utf8**" character set with "**utf8_general_ci**" collation and some in "**latin1**" with "**latin1_swedish_ci**" collation. So sometimes its getting stuck i don't know why. I changed the character set of every column to "latin1" now its not getting stuck.

Execute this query to check the character set of columns.

```
SELECT table_name,column_name,character_set_name,data_type FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE table_schema = "DbName"
```

For character set conversion you can take help from this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-conversion.html